# Spring JSR-303 ConstraintValidator not support list.add()

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I've met such a misundestrood:
I've made a validation using my own annotation `@Category` and class `CategoryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Category, String>`

All is about list.add() which causes (without it works properly):

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception
>   during isValid call.

Can someone give me any explaination?

**CategoryValidator**

```
@Component
public class CategoryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Category, String> {

@Autowired
ProductService productService;

List<String> allowedCategories;

@Override
public void initialize(Category constraintAnnotation) {
    allowedCategories = Arrays.asList(constraintAnnotation.allowedCategories());
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    // This .add() it not working here
    // allowedCategories.add("Laptop"); 

    for (String category : allowedCategories) {
        if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

**Category**

```
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CategoryValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Category {
String message() default "{com.ehr.webstore.validator.Category.message}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

String[] allowedCategories();
}
```

**Product**

```
public class Product {
/* [...] */
@Category(allowedCategories = {"Laptop", "Tablet", "Smart Phone", "Another"})
private String category;
/* [...] */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it would be easier with the full stacktrace but I think your issue is that you can't add an element to a `List` created by `Arrays.asList()`: it is immutable.

If you want to be able to add new elements, you need to do something like: `new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( ... ) )`.

Comment: Yea man, that's the point! `List` is just immutable. It works for `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(constraintAnnotation.allowedCategories()));` instead of `Arrays.asList(constraintAnnotation.allowedCategories());` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that it’s a bad idea to add elements to the list in the isValid() method as the element will be added each time an object is validated.